# Disable/Readonly admin options Magento 1

Tags: php, magento-1, xml, catalog

How can I **disable** the `size` **option** for catalog products in Magento 1. I've searched Google and StackOverflow and I can't find a good solution.

Is there someone that can help me?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is this to disable the output of the `size` attribute in layered nav/on the product page etc?

Comment: When i edit catalog_product in the admin, there is an option 'size' (dorpdown) and i want to disable this option on front-end level.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable Size from product attributes.

> Go to Admin section -> Catalog -> Attributes -> Manage Attributes Sets

From Groups find 'Size' and drag it to *Unassigned Attributes*

Save and clear cache.

Comment: That is deleting the option not disable the dropdown i guess.

Comment: Do you want to show it but don't want to enable it to change options at front end?

Comment: I want to set it on readonly.