# php.ini on magento cloud readonly

Tags: magento2, php, cache, magento-cloud, memory-limit

I need increase some values in my php.ini from magento-cloud environment, but with my user with admin roles opens the file in onlyread mode.

Searching I found this, wasn't succesfully
[Disable/Readonly admin options Magento 1](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/204663/disable-readonly-admin-options-magento-1)
and this
[Read-Only Product Backend attribute](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/784/read-only-product-backend-attribute)

Even I've create a new user with admin role, in my web-cloud platform it hasn't option admin edition as this thread says:
https://github.com/magento/devdocs/issues/1786

Hoping any help, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For magento cloud, the production is in read-only mode. You have to change & push the codechanges from lower environments (staging, integration, etc) into production.
Another option is to set the changes in the environment-specific variables in magento.cloud (https://devdocs.magento.com/cloud/env/working-with-variables.html)

Comment: Done. Thanks dude